# SQL Server: count by group (one column)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, count, group-by

I am new to SQL Server and hope you can help me with the following:

I have a table with multiple columns out of which one column is called categoryX. 
There are different categories (text) in **column categoryX** and I would like to know how many items there are in the table in total + **how many items counted by category** in column categoryX.

The result should be something like:

```
categoryA: 10
categoryB: 5
categoryC: 3
```

and so on

**So far I have the following - this would give me the list grouped by category but not the count for each group:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FetchRequests]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT  categoryX
FROM    LogRequests
WHERE   logStatus = 'active'
AND workStatus != 'live'
GROUP BY    categoryX
FOR XML PATH('categoryX'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
END
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim

Comment: Can you just do `SELECT  categoryX, COUNT(*) ...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FetchRequests]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT categoryX + ': ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),TotalCount) AS Result
FROM
(
    SELECT  categoryX,
            COUNT(*) AS TotalCount
    FROM    LogRequests
    WHERE   logStatus = 'active'
    AND workStatus != 'live'
    GROUP BY    categoryX
) AS T
FOR XML PATH('categoryX'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
END
```

Comment: Perfect - exactly what I was looking for. Can you explain what the following line does ? CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),TotalCount) AS Result

Comment: It converts TotalCount which is by default an `INT` to a `VARCHAR` which is of a string type. This needs to happen because you cannot have `+` with `INT` and `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Got it - thanks a lot ! When I try to save this I get the following error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure FetchRequests, Line 25 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.

Comment: Yes, i forgot to add an allias to the sub-query.